# Редирект после отправки формы

Tags: php, mysql, редирект

Есть форма, которая отправляет данные в базу. После успешной отправки появляется сообщение, что данные добавлены. Нужно сделать так, чтобы после успешкой отправки и добавления данных меня не отправляло на страницу с сообщением, а оставило на этой же странице (index.php).

Файл form.php

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

    $id = trim($_REQUEST['id']);
    $date = trim($_REQUEST['date']);
    $name = trim($_REQUEST['name']);
    $phone = trim($_REQUEST['phone']);
    $address = trim($_REQUEST['address']);
    $contract_number = trim($_REQUEST['contract_number']);
    $login = trim($_REQUEST['login']);
    $credit_amount = trim($_REQUEST['credit_amount']);
    $months = trim($_REQUEST['months']);
    $start_amount = trim($_REQUEST['start_amount']);
    $balance = trim($_REQUEST['balance']);
    $monthly_payment = trim($_REQUEST['monthly_payment']);
    $rate = trim($_REQUEST['rate']);
    $total = trim($_REQUEST['total']);

    $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO abons_table (id, date, name, phone, address, contract_number, 
        login, credit_amount, months, start_amount, balance, monthly_payment, rate, total)" .
        "VALUES ('{$id}', '{$date}', '{$name}', '{$phone}', '{$address}', '{$contract_number}',
        '{$login}', '{$credit_amount}', '{$months}', '{$start_amount}', '{$balance}', '{$monthly_payment}',
        '{$rate}', '{$total}');";

    mysql_query($insert_sql) or die (mysql_error());
    //if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){}
    if ($insert_sql=='true') {
    //header('Location: localhost/bospor/index.php');
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=localhost/bospor/index.php">';
    }
    echo "<p>Addition successful</p>";

?>
```

Пытался несколькими способами (в самом конце). Не получилось. Подскажите пожалуйста что может быть не так.

Выглядит это пока так:
[image: index.php]

И переводит меня сюда:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему тем, что просто без всяких условий написал

```
header('Location: ../index.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=localhost/bospor/index.php">';
```

Поменяйте на:

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: Отправляет данные и переходит на пустую страницу формы

Comment: Вам нужно отправить и оставить форму заполненной?

Comment: Можно заполненной, можно пустой. В принципе, пока без разницы. Главное чтобы форма закрывалась и я остался на индексной странице. Ну или даже не оставался, а чтобы страница хотя бы просто обновлялась после успешной отправки. Сейчас прикреплю еще скрины в вопрос.

Comment: Обновляться будет. Вы попробовали?

Comment: Ваш вариант? Да. Ничего не изменилось. Меня так же кидает на пустую страницу form.php. В конце вопроса на скриншотах показано как оно все у меня происходит.

Answer (score 0):

отправлять форму аяксово, если форма валидная и попала в базу --> присылать ответ о успешном выполнении отправки данных в базу.
при получении на стороне клиента сообщения о успешной отправке --> показывать всплывающий\затухающий и тд. попап о успешном выполнении операции.

Comment: Мне по сути не нужен ответ, а нужно закрытие формы и открытие той же страницы на которой я и был.

Comment: Ну красота аяксовой отправки в том, что вы вообще никуда не переходите. А ответ в общих чертах нужен для того, чтоб вы знали, что данные на стороне сервера обработаны верно и предприняли по этому поводу что-то если надо ( например обнулили поля формы )